# Why it does not use deterministic calculus

Tags: calculus

[image]

We already define in equation (5) that $dr(t) = -ar(t)dt$.

So I think the leftside of equation (7) should be $-ar(t)dt$. But I don't know where $e^{-at}dC$ came from.

Therefore I think, ordinary calculus which is applied to the deterministic function is not applied this derivation.

I want to know the reason why.

Comment: That image doesn't show what they are deriving. That the model is stochastic is obvious from (1-4).

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Even though it is not full source, It defines 'equal'($dr(t) = -ar(t)dt$) in equation (5) and just put it in equation (1). Then where $e^{-at}dC$ came from? The image is the first page of derivation and after that image, it doesn't deal with the stuff related to derivation of equation (7).

Comment: At first glance this equation (5) is confusing because it suggests that $r(t)$ is deterministic. I would have skipped that and would have written lets define a stochastic $C(t)$ by $r(t)=C(t)e^{-at}$.